# Homepage Scrolling and Icon laylout like Default Apple

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a way i can create the same layout as the apple homepage screen?

I want to create a app with 50 icons, and you can scroll right to see the rest, or scroll left to get a custom search page for something.

I'm trying to find an example of how i can use Page Control and place my icons so they scroll like the apple app page.

Any assistance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at Facebook's Three20 library

http://three20.info/showcase/launcher

Answer (score 2):

Page controls are in fact UIScrollView with pagingEnabled set to YES.

read the apple doc on UIScrolView !

Comment: Thanks, But i decided to go with Three20's Library!!

Answer (score 0):

Just be aware of:

#
8.3

Apps which appear confusingly similar to an existing Apple product or advertising theme will be rejected

From https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html